# Subgroup of invertible upper triangular matrices is solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solvable-groups

Like the title said, I am trying to prove the following claim:

"$B = \{M\in GL_n(\mathbb{R}): M$ is upper triangular $\}$ " 
is a solvable group.

So my idea was to calculate the derived series of $B$ and show that it terminates at the trivial group $G_k = \{I_n\}$. I managed to compute the first derived group $[B,B]$, or the commutator subgroup of $B$, which is just $[B,B] = B\, \cap SL_n(\mathbb{R})$. However, I am stuck trying to compute the next derived commutator subgroup.

I would mostly appreciate a hint, not a full solution. Thanks!

Comment: Have you already tried to calculate the commutator of two upper trianglular matrices? Well, do...and observe you get an **strictly** upper triangular matrix. After that you're done, because when working with the commutator subgroup $\;B'\;$ , you already have a group with all its matrices *nilpotent*.

Comment: The commutator of two upper triangular matrices is of the form "I+(strictly upper triangular)".

Comment: donAntonio are you saying that if the all the matrices in $B'$ are nilpotent, then the group itself is solvable? Is there anyway to see this without using the language of Lie algebra?