# Show that upper triangular matrices group is solvable

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, solvable-groups

I want to prove that the group 
$$B_n =  \{ \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_{1,2} & \cdots &   b_{1,n} \\ & \ddots & & \vdots \\ & & a_{n-1} & b_{n-1, n} \\ & & &  a_n \end{pmatrix}  | b_{ij} \in F, a_i \in F^* \} $$

is solvable.

I though about using the homomorphism $f: B_n \rightarrow (F^*)^n$  , which is declared $$f(\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_{1,2} & \cdots &   b_{1,n} \\ & \ddots & & \vdots \\ & & a_{n-1} & b_{n-1, n} \\ & & &  a_n \end{pmatrix}) = (a_1,....,a_n)$$

this way, I get 
$$Kerf = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b_{1,2} & \cdots &   b_{1,n} \\ & \ddots & & \vdots \\ & & 1 & b_{n-1, n} \\ & & &  1 \end{pmatrix}  | b_{ij} \in F* \} $$

and since $Ker(f) \lhd B_n$ I thought about using the theorem which says that: if $N \lhd G$ is solvable and $G/N$ is solvable, then G is also solvable.

I also know that $Im(f) = (F^*)^n$.

I got stuck proving that $Ker(f)$ and $B_n/Ker(f)$ are solvable

Help would be appreciated

Comment: See Exercise 3 [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiTg_OLnLviAhUBa1AKHTDdAAsQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww2.math.ethz.ch%2Feducation%2Fbachelor%2Flectures%2Ffs2015%2Fmath%2Falgebra2%2FSerie8s&usg=AOvVaw0wr8XdjLt0VkmoKwqsbsci), with solution! See also the comments for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977389/subgroup-of-invertible-upper-triangular-matrices-is-solvable).

Comment: Thanks! that exercise really helped me